# C# gives strange error during resolution of extension methods of generic type

Tags: c#, generics, extension-methods

I have 3 C# projects: LibraryA, LibraryB and LibraryC, such that LibraryB references LibraryA and LibraryC references LibraryB. Notice that LibraryC does not reference LibraryA.

In LibraryA there is a single class: ClassA.

In LibraryC there is a class ClassC with following code:

```
public class ClassC
{
    public void f()
    {
        new ClassB<int>().MethodA();
    }
}
```

And in LibraryB:

```
public class ClassB<T> {}

public static class BExtensions {
    public static void MethodA<T>(this ClassB<T> should){}
}

public static class BAExtensions {
    public static void MethodA(this ClassB<ClassA> should){}
}
```

My solution does not compile saying that I have to add reference from LibraryC to LibraryA.
Why does compiler behave that way? Is it documented somewhere in language spec?

Just as a background. In my unit tests I am trying to have syntax like this:

```
var x = 1 + 1;
x.Should().Equal(2);
```

For some types I need kind of 'specializations'(c++ analogy) of Equal method for types, but I would prefer those 'specializations' to be somewhere near all other 'Should()' code.

Comment: Because LibraryB exposes definitions which are directly including things from Library A. So if you want to use LibraryB, you need LibraryA anyway.

Comment: Your code will not run without all 3 aseemblies, right? Because C uses B and B uses A. So what is the question? Did you exptect your code to run with only the B and C assembly? Or do you think it's odd that you, manually, need to reference A from C ? The refences from B to C and from A to B, does it have "true" in "Copy Local" property (in Visual Studio) ?

Comment: Maarten, SteenT, thank you for help, but I am seeking a theoretical basis of what is happening in the first place. FYI, my code will compile if I, for example wrap BAExtensions with a namespace and do not include it in the file with ClassC.

Comment: @SteenT: The way I understand the question, LibraryC transitively references LibraryA through LibraryB anyway, so intuitively, there should be no need to add that reference explicitly. So I'd say the question boils down to "why do we have to make transitive references explicit?" - which I think is a valid question.

Comment: @ironic: One possible explanation could be that whoever decided this was of the opinion that explicit dependencies are better for maintainability than implicit ones. Which is something I would agree to.

Comment: @chris, I am also totally agree with that statement. However, it is not exactly that case. In this case LibraryC does not actually have any dependencies on LibraryA, since it does not use BAExtensions.